# Cover background image is not scaling properly?

Tags: html, css, background, webkit

I'm trying to figure out exactly why my webkit cover background isn't scaling properly on some pages on my site.

The URL is http://www.finestgc.com/.  On the homepage, you can see that the cover background image is scaling properly, the issue lies on the other pages, such as: http://www.finestgc.com/general.html where you can see the image is scaling entirely too big.

Could a CSS/HTML expert help me determine the reason this is occurring?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because your other page is much bigger.

Comment: Why would it relate to the vertical height of the fixed width div?

Comment: That's the way that background-size:cover works which is applied to your body.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there any other way to do what I need, then?

Comment: I suppose one answer is have one very large image that could be used on even the largest of your pages. It would look normal on the largest and be scaled down on the smaller ones. Aside from that, perhaps background-size:cover isn't what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file, change this:

```
body
{
    background: url('images/blueprint.png') #222 no-repeat;
    ....
}
```

to:

```
body
{
    background: url('images/blueprint.png') #222 no-repeat fixed;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second page http://www.finestgc.com/general.html

In **CSS** on body add this code

> background-attachment:fixed;